# Typescript type dependant on boolean value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

Say I have a component with a prop `isActive`, which takes one or another object from redux store with different props depending on `isActive` value, like this:

```
const componentState: ActiveType | PassiveType = useSelector((state: RootState) => (isActive ? selectActiveObj(state) : selectPassiveObj(state));
```

Then it uses it while checking again whether `isActive` is true or not, to know how to use the data. Typescript, of course, doesn't pick the check and will complain that `Property 'active_id' does not exist on type 'PassiveProps'`

What's the general approach here, can I even do it like this?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your issue correctly, but you maybe want to read about TypeGuards. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Very nice and very close, thank you, I could go with it. However, maybe I'm asking for too much from TS, but I was hoping it's possible to do in one check (later in the code while using the data), since if I have say 5 objects that all depend on this flag I'd have to do 5 type guards for each.